# Can you perform a coup de grace if you don't have a full-round action?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e

Can a zombie or a staggered creature perform a coup de grace? 
I'm wonder for both 3.5 and Pathfinder.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes

Because of its interaction with the action economy, the option is rarely used, but in both games a creature can take a standard action in two successive turns to perform a full round action (see [here](http://dndsrd.net/actionsInCombat.html#start-complete-full-round-action) for *3.5e* and [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/) under Start/Complete Full-Round Action for *Pathfinder*). That is, the creature, at the end of the first turn, takes a standard action to *start* the full-round action, then, at the beginning of the second turn, takes a standard action to *finish* the full round action. In both games, however, some full-round actions remain impossible for the creature to perform, but a coup de grace shouldn't be among these.

Comment: As I recall, that option is only available when you _cannot_ use a full-round action normally, not an option you can always use.

Comment: @KRyan Not so far as I'm aware. A partial charge, for example, can only be taken when you're, like, *slowed* or whatever, but otherwise it's a general option available to anybody. You can follow the links to confirm.

Comment: Ah, I must have been conflating partial charges with the general option.

Comment: @KRyan It looks like you're wrong this time. And I can see where the confusion may come from. The PHB gives an example where a PC is limited to a standard action. But this example starts with 'for instance', thus it is not the only situation where this action is allowed. But it is for sure one of that few situations where it can be worth taking.